# Can't get excel or LibroOffice to read my string

Tags: excel, csv

```
=COUNTIFS(AX1:AX2008,"sub",B1:B2008,">= 20:00",C1:C2008,"<= 8:00",D1:D2008,"<>A")
```

Know nothing about this stuff. So I'm trying to count the sum of names that punched in from 20:00 pm to 8 am that had the string "sub" in their job description but exclude the ones that started with Character "A". But when I try to separately test "sub" on it's own, I get 0 as an answer, which means I'm not entering the string correctly somehow. Obviously can't test the rest either

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(AX1:AX2008,"*sub*",...`

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(AX1:AX2008,"*sub*",B1:B2008, ">= 20:00",C1:C2008, "<= 8:00", D1:D2008,"<>A")`  In addition to what @TimWilliams stated, you are missing some `,`.

Comment: you may not want a space between the >= and the 20:00  ">=20:00" but I am not positive on that.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, yes I had all the commas and * and couldn't get it to work

Comment: 20:00 is a string or excel time formatted as time?  test your data with istext(B1) or isnumber(B1)

Answer (score 0):

In CSV that will be considered as 8 separate values, so you can put it in quotes

```
"=COUNTIFS(AX1:AX2008,""*sub*"",B1:B2008,"">=20/24"",C1:C2008,""<=8/24"",D1:D2008,""<>A"")"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did exactly as you said. But it still has a problem with ""*sub*"" , it keeps returning 0 on its own and when combined with the rest of the formula , it return ERR:509

Comment: Stackoverflow deleted the asterisk, but it's in there

Comment: 509 is [Missing operator](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/General_error_codes) error so maybe something like `,"=*sub*",` in the formula (not in the CSV file). I can't test it in LibreOffice so I leave it to you to figure it out. It works in Excel